# Choose between fixed and variable timestep in different physics simulations

Tags: game-physics, timedelta

I know that physics simulations in fixed time steps can be very CPU demanding.
Should I prioritize the physics in this way(for best performance):

**Variable time step:**

- Visual only particle effects based on physics(e.g. velocity verlet integration with constant acceleration)
- Other visual stuff based on physics, but don't interact with the scene.
- Objects based on this simple equation: p_new(dt) = p_old + v * dt, where v is constant.
- Objects based on this equation: p(dt) = p_0 + **v_0** * dt + 1/2 * **a** * dt^2,
  where **v_o** and **a** is constant.

**Fixed time step, Physics + collision detection.**

- Ragdoll
- Player movement based on physics.
- Shoot projectiles based on physics.

Is this ok? Should the collision detection use fixed time steps?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this ok? Should the collision detection use fixed time steps?

It depends on your project. If the *"visual stuff"* you describe behave physically (ie suffer forces from physics forces, interactions or collisions), then if they are set to a timestep different from the physics' engine, you may start having problems.

But, since they are *"visual stuff"*, and as such I'm assuming they aren't critical to the gameplay, then the problems may not be *noticeable* or may be sufficiently *rare* enough for your game to get away with doing it.

In other words, you can certainly *try*... But whether or not *"it's ok" (you will or will not run into problems) depends on the project.

---

PS: If you want to optimize, there are things that will have much greater impact (assuming you haven't already optimized them).

One of the main examples (if not *the* main example) of a specific thing that has huge impact on game performance is reducing the `draw calls`. But explaining it, or other optimizations, here is not appropriate since that's not the question, and there are plenty of other Q&As here on SO, and also on [GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) that already discuss and answer what those optimizations are, why they have such impact, and how to apply them.

Comment: Yeah, because my "visual" stuff is entirely simulated on the GPU and it would be a disaster to run multiple draw calls when the simulation needs to catch up with fixed time steps...... This function: p(dt) = emitterPos + v * dt is perfectly safe for different(variable) time steps, but what about p(dt) = emitterPos + v * dt + 1/2 * a * dt^2? if the velocity and acceleration(in this case, gravity) is constant.

Comment: Yes, fewer draw calls is much better. I'm using instancing when I need to draw multiple particle systems of the same type.